# Regex having issues in Apex

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I found a Regex which retrieves the Parent domain from a URL. When I tried using the same Regex Expression in Apex using Pattern and Matcher, it's giving me an error of:

> Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '(\w+.\w+)$'. Illegal character sequence \w' in string literal.

Below is my code:

```
Account aa = [SELECT id, Website from Account WHERE Id = '0016F00002QeRqw'];
String d = aa.Website;
String regexx = '(\w+\.\w+)$';
Pattern mPat = Pattern.compile(regexx);
Matcher myMatch = mPat.matcher(d);
system.debug('--'+myMatch);
```

[Link to the Regex](https://regex101.com/r/wD8eP2/1)

I am not that good in the Regex and could use some help finding the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apex [Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods.htm?search_text=Pattern) class behaves like Java [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. According to Java documentation you have to escape backslash if it is present in regex expression

> The backslash character ('\') serves to introduce escaped constructs,
>   as defined in the table above, as well as to quote characters that
>   otherwise would be interpreted as unescaped constructs. Thus the
>   expression `\\` matches a single backslash and `\{` matches a left brace.

---

Just escape `\` in your regex with additional backslashes. You want to have regex `(\\w+\\.\\w+)$`

---

```
Account aa = [SELECT id, Website from Account WHERE Id = '0016F00002QeRqw'];
String d = aa.Website;
String regexx = '(\\w+\\.\\w+)$';
Pattern mPat = Pattern.compile(regexx);
Matcher myMatch = mPat.matcher(d);
myMatch.find();
System.debug('Domain:' + myMatch.group());
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to dive deeper into regular expressions now.